# Site name on RefineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I'm use the RefineryCMS based on rails.
Where is Refinery CMS save site name? How can I make multilanguage site name?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your site name in settings (yoursite/refinery/settings).

For multilang you can do something like this:

```
  if I18n.locale.to_s == 'fr'
    # sets sitename to "My Site name in French"
    RefinerySetting.set(:site_name, "My Site name in French")
  else
    # displays site name from settings if defined otherwise displays "My site"
    RefinerySetting.find_or_set(:site_name, "My site")
  end
```

Comment: put it into `controllers/application_controller.rb`. if you want to save translation in database look at `globalize3` gem, refinery uses it.

Comment: ok? it's work, thanks, but how can I save site name in db? translation for site_name?

Answer (score 0):

To set the company name open the file app/controllers/application_controller.rb and add this to it:

```
Refinery::Core.configure do |config|
config.site_name = "my site name"
end
```